# Electric service wire size

Tags: electrical-panel, wire

I have to put in a new service wire I was Given service wire that was told was ok. they said it was 4/0 aluminum. I looked at the jacket and it said, 3 cdr awg 2 compact al. aluminaflex. I am putting in a 200 amp meter. The wire has 2 insulated wires and and 1 non insulated. I am not a electrician im just trying to hang it all and have a electrician come in and do the final part. Is the wire I have ok to use?

Comment: "3 CDR"= three insulated, hot conductor wires. AWG= American Wire Gauge, a number before it is the wire size (ie 12 AWG is a 12 gauge diameter wire). The "4/0" shows the size of the three ("3CDR")    aluminum conductors.

Comment: You are trying the typical "I'll do the grunt work and have a professional do 'the hookups'" routine. It has been shown that this method is hardly ever the right way to go. What you are doing IS the hard part, and the most code intensive part. Who told you AWG2 wire was 4/0?? There is a huge difference in size and they are blatantly obvious to tell apart. I would forgo trying to "hang it all" and let someone who knows what they are doing install this service correctly.

Comment: The two insulated wires have three conductors each?  Three 2 AWG?  if so, that is almost equivalent to a 4/0.  AWG2 is 66,369 circular mils.  3 times that is 199,107.  4/0 is 211,592.  4/0 Aluminum is rated for a 200A service feeder.  I am not sure about using 3 conductors per phase though, that wouldn't be permitted where I live for residential service.